# What does this bracket notation $\langle\phi(x),v\rangle$ mean?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, papers, math, notation

I found it at the bottom of page 2 of the paper [Intriguing properties of neural networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6199.pdf) (2014), in the form of

$$\underset{x\in\mathcal{I}}{\mathrm{arg\,max}}\langle\phi(x),v\rangle$$

Answer (score 1):

It is the inner product which in this case is the dot product.

Comment: What’s your intended difference between inner product and dot product? What case they have to be interpreted differently?

Comment: Often the simplified notations $a^Tb$ or $a·b$ are used for the Euklidean scalar product, while the braket notation is used for a general scalar product with an s.p.d. matrix in the middle.